# Clear cache of APM-form

Tags: cors, amp-html, cache-control

I had created APM page with apm-form element. The form is working perfectly fine on my server and local env. However, when I access website form AMP url I can't send anything. In my console I getting this error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://example.co.uk/form.php?_gl=....GSg..&__amp_source_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.co.uk' from origin 'https://example-co-uk.cdn.ampproject.org' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://example.test' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I know how to Fix Cors issue. However, please note that

> header has a value 'http://example.test'

Amp-form has setup action-xhr to //example.co.uk/form.php. 
In form.php all headers are set:

```
header('AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: https://example.co.uk');
header("AMP-Same-Origin: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example-co-uk.ampproject.org");
header ("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length, X-JSON");
header ("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
```

Previously when I was developing this page. I send to the server versions of form.php with example.test in header section. I am assuming that Google somehow cached this example.test. I am not sure where is cached and how to clear this cache.

I was trying to update cache using  https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-cache . I stuck as well I got 404 from Google
[image]

Any suggestion how tell AMP that example.test is replaced with example.co.uk ?

Answer (score 0):

When the Cache Update is not working - you could:

1) Update the Sitemap and change the last update stamp of the page 
(google bot will check that)

2) You could change the Header to

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*'
```

3) Leave it like that - google is said to update the cache every 24 hours.